# Improvement to my horrible switch statement for regex matching

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, switch-statement

I'm trying to get away from using horrible switch cases in node.js. I am looking for a more efficient way of testing an input against various regex cases. Dependent on the case that is matched I either fire an event or I do some transformation of the input before running another function.

To save having a really long block of code I have cut down my function to the skeleton below so it shows a focus on the switch.

I've taken a look at the possibility of using .map to return a true false but I'm unsure how best to implement that also.

Any advise or suggestions on the best way to do this?

```
function ParseLogMessages(message, config, callback){
var _this = this;

try {
//Define regex in order to match strings based on case
_this.to_group = new RegExp("^\\[\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\]\\s+\\w+\\s+tg+\\s\\>{3}");
_this.from_group=new RegExp("^\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\]\\s\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\>{3}");
_this.to_person = new RegExp("^\\[\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\]\\s[a-zA-Z0-9 \\- _]+\\s\\<{3}.+");
_this.from_person = new RegExp("^\\[\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\]\\s\\w+\\s\\>{3}");
_this.contact = new RegExp("(User #+\\d+:)");


_this.contact = new RegExp("(User #+\\d+:)");

//Test message against each to find type
switch (true){
    //Message sent to a group chat
    case _this.to_group.test(_this.payload.raw):
    break;

    //Message from a group chat
    case _this.from_group.test(_this.payload.raw):
    break;

    //Message sent to a person from the bot
    case _this.to_person.test(_this.payload.raw):
    break;

    //Message sent from a person to the bot
    case _this.from_person.test(_this.payload.raw):         
    break;

    //Contact shared
    case _this.contact.test(_this.payload.raw):     
    break;

    default:
    break;


}

callback(null,"Logfile message parsed ok!");

  } catch(err) {
    log.error(err);
    return callback(err,null);
  }

}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the switch, the alternative is probably a bunch of `if` statements instead ?

Comment: I'm +1ing this for the title, I'd use a more real parser.

Comment: @adeneo it can still get a lot tidier than the switch, as my answer hopefully shows.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - not sure if doing freaky shit with regex'es as keys to functions, using `let` etc. is tidier, and there are no assoc arrays, just objects. Using a loop shortens the code, but it basically does the same thing, and it's not really easier to read, it, well, just shortens the code ?

Comment: @adeneo: objects are JS's idea of assoc arrays; not all AAs are implemented the same way, you know. As far as the rest, connecting "pattern" with {code} as closely as possible seems tidy by definition; the only question you can ask is whether it's understandable enough for yourself and coworkers. Not sure what you mean about `let`, but write an answer for that?

Comment: You're using the `let` keyword, used to be you'd have to run node with the "harmony" setting to even get that working, and it's not something I would do in production code, but I'm not paying attention to all the cutting edge stuff, maybe @BenjaminGruenbaum knows the status of using `let` in Node as of today ?

Comment: @adeneo not implemented in v8, requires a transpiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an array of regex/function pairs and loop through the array:

```
_this.tests = [
    { regex: new RegExp("^\\[\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\]\\s+\\w+\\s+tg+\\s\\>{3}"), // to_group
      action: ... // action for to_group
    },
    { regex : new RegExp("^\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\]\\s\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\>{3}"), // from_group
      action: ... // action for from_group
    },
    // etc.
];
```

Then you can loop through the array, testing, and breaking when the test works:

```
for (i=0; i<tests.length; ++i) {
    if (tests[i].regex.test(_this.payload.raw) {
        tests[i].action();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm happy to see we had the same idea independently!

Comment: This is what I would have answered but I didn't have time to write out the code example :)

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Yes, we have very similar answers. However, using `for..in` will result in an unpredictable iteration order through the regexes. If the order of testing is important (and I see no basis for assuming that at most one regex would match the payload data), then one should use an array and go through by index.

Comment: @TedHopp My regex instances do depend on a specific order of execution as you suggest. Thanks for picking up on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the objects in an array and call the test function until one returns true:

```
var o = [
  _this.to_group,
  _this.from_group,
  _this.to_person,
  _this.from_person,
  _this.contact
];
for (var i in o) {
  if (o[i].test(_this.payload.raw)) {
    // got a match
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to convert that into an associative array and match with a loop. Untested code that should work:

```
let patterns = {
    "^\\[\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\]\\s+\\w+\\s+tg+\\s\\>{3}": funcToGroup /* code for this case, preferably a [reference to a] function object without the parens */,
    "^\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\]\\s\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\>{3}": function () {
        // An inline anonymous function is also fine
    },
    "^\\[\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\]\\s[a-zA-Z0-9 \\- _]+\\s\\<{3}.+": funcToPerson,
    "^\\[\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\]\\s\\w+\\s\\>{3}": funcFromPerson,
    "(User #+\\d+:)": funcContactShared
};

for (let pat in _this.patterns) {
    if (new RegExp(pat).test(_this.payload.raw)) {
        _this.patterns[pat]();  // Actually execute the relevant case
    }
}
```

That should handle all the code within the `try` block.